# Database not adding all fields

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm adding data to a DB table and some of the data is going in and some is not. I've recheck the field names to make sure they are correct.

The result of dd($request) is below:

[[image: results of dd]]

Controller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    //

    Donation::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->action('DonationController@index');
}
```

[[image: Database results]]

Comment: In the model Donation, are the fields defined in $fillable?

Comment: You're correct.  I had a typo in each of those fields.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you accept the answer if it worked for you? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel has a security mechanism whereby you need to specifically define which fields you want to allow to be filled, in this case mass assignable. More info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment)

So in this case, in your `Donation` model, please ensure that the fields have been defined in the `$fillable` array as such

```
protected $fillable = ['notes', 'another_field', 'another_field_2'];
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use `protected $guarded = [..];` to define protected fields.

Comment: Or my favourite: don't make anything `$fillable` and use `$model->forceFill($suff)` when you're 100% about your validation. Better yet `$model->forceFill($request->only(['field1', 'field2'...]));`